# Strip out html elements using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have the following html:

```
<div class="leftColumn">
  <div>
     <div class="static">
      .............................
     </div>  
     text1
     <br>
     text2
     <br>
     (222) 123 - 4567
     <br>
     <div class="summary">
     .........................
     </div>
  </div>
```

I've just been shown that the way to get the text is

```
soup.select('.leftColumn div')[0].text.split()
```

This works but there is so much junk left over from the 2 divs that it is very difficult to pick out the text I need reliably. Is there a way to remove the 2 classes (static and summary ) which would make it much easier to process the remainder?

Comment: This may help (although it is for bs3...): http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Removing%20elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example based on your snippet:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = """
<div class="leftColumn">
  <div>
     <div class="static">
      .............................
     </div>
     text1
     <br>
     text2
     <br>
     (222) 123 - 4567
     <br>
     <div class="summary">
     .........................
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

# Find divs with class "static" or "summary" and remove them using `extract`
div_nodes = soup.find_all('div', {'class': ['static', 'summary']})
[div.extract() for div in div_nodes]

print soup.text.split()
```

If you run the code, you will see that the static and summary divs are removed, and you get:

```
[u'text1', u'text2', u'(222)', u'123', u'-', u'4567']
```